# Track Memory Usage on Website

Tags: cakephp

One of my cakephp websites my business is hosting keeps exhausting it's allowed memory and I figure I can't just keep increasing and increasing the amount this website is allowed.  **Is there a way for me to track which processes or scripts of my website are hogging so much memory so that I may try and fix the error?**
Thanks,

Comment: you have to check it manually generally images holding much space and find out unnecessary files

Comment: Manually?  How would I do that?  Sorry I should have clarified, certain scripts or tasks seem to hog a lot of memory.  I did not mean disk space.

Comment: I'd be in favour of profiling tools like for example Xdebug or Blackfire.